# sync files recursively between two folders where files are less than 24 hours old

Tags: bash, scripting, find, rsync

I want to find all the files under a directory which are within 24 hours then rsync those files with another server.

There are some old files that I do not want to transfer, however if those old files are updated then I do.

I was thinking of writing a script with: find and the -ctime parameter and redirect that output to a file, but I don't know how to get rsync to effectively use that, or if there is a better way to transfer a set of files which have changed in the last 24 hours.

This process needs to be run very frequently, so am not looking for something too inefficient. (such as using ftp and sending everything each time).

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. It looks like `--include-from` is not enough, as the default behavior is to include everything. You need to explicitly tell it to `--exclude` everything in order for it to act like a white list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /some/dir && rsync -av --files-from=<(find . -mtime 0 -printf "%p\n") <other stuff>
```

It uses **Process Substitution** `<( )` to replace the `find` command with a named fifo and gives that fifo's name to `rsync` to read as what to include in the sync.

#### Update

In light of Kyle's answer, it definitely appears that `--files-from` is more appropriate than `--include-from`; although both will work. Answer updated

Comment: `rsync` is a one way, unidirectional sync system. Use `unison` if two-way, bidirectional sync system is needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh
thefiles=/tmp/files.$$
LOCALDIR=/path/to/local/dir
REMOTEDIR=/path/to/remote/dir
REMOTEHOST=remote.host
changetime=24h

cd $LOCALDIR || { echo cd failed 1>&2; exit 1; }

trap 'rm -f $thefiles' 0

find . -type f -ctime -$changetime -print > $thefiles
rsync -v -n --archive --files-from=$thefiles . $REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEDIR
```

This script runs find in $LOCALDIR, dumping the results into a file, then tells rsync to use the file contents as a list of files to transfer to the directory $REMOTEDIR on the host $REMOTEHOST.  The script chdir's into $LOCALDIR because the rsync command needs relative paths, not absolute ones.  I left -v -n in the rsync args so you can see what this does without copying anything; remove -n when you're satisfied the script does what you want.