# How to sync two directories?

Tags: rsync

I have an "A" HDD (1,5TB) next to me (on a netbook running OpenBSD 5.1, it's a fileserver)
And I have a "B" HDD (1,5TB) 200km's away from me on an OpenWrt 10.04 router (also "fileserver").

I always put files on the netbook next to me. I need to sync this local storage (on the OpenBSD netbook) with the B storage 200 km's away with max 30 KByte/sec speed. I found a solution for this via google :)

[sync files recursively between two folders where files are less than 24 hours old](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30204/sync-files-recursively-between-two-folders-where-files-are-less-than-24-hours-ol)

**Question**: How can I configure that, when I sync to the "B" storage that they will not see these "half-uploaded" files?
So I'm searching for a solution like: "If file is not fully copied from A to B, then put a dot before it's name, so they will not see as it is a hidden file.. if the upload finishes to a file, then after that the dot must be removed from their name, so that they can see it.."

Comment: `rsync`'s default behaviour is exactly that. It uses a separate, hidden file while transferring. After the transfer is done, the hidden file replaces the target file. You can *defeat* this behaviour using `--in-place`, but I'd class that as a Bad Idea in average use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour when using `rsync`. From `man rsync`:

```
   --inplace
          This  option  changes  how  rsync transfers a file when its data
          needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a
          new  copy  of  the file and moving it into place when it is com-
          plete, rsync instead writes the updated  data  directly  to  the
          destination file.
```